# How to fuse 4-bit LLAMA weights with LoRA ones into one .pt file?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, alpaca

I followed [this manual](https://github.com/s4rduk4r/alpaca_lora_4bit_readme/blob/main/README.md) and got `llama-7b-hf-int4` (got `llama-7b-4bit.pt` ) and `samwit/alpaca7B-lora` (got `adapter_model.bin`). Now I want to merge them into a single .pt 4bit model. How to do such a thing?

Why I need this:

1. current lama.cpp supports only legacy 4-bit single file models.
2. 4-bit fine-tuners generate small alpaca fine-tuned mini models.
3. only 4-bit alpaca tuning is available for my current setup; thus, I need to know how to apply/merge one into another.

Comment: What is wrong with the .pt file you already have?